# azure media text watermark on video set on right side corner c#

Tags: azure-media-services, video-watermarking

Using Azure media Service we can Create an overlay an image onto an existing video which I had achieved using your documentation. But can we create an overlay(Watermark) a text onto an existing video and second.

How can we set watermark text/image on right side corner. I went through all documentation but haven't get any solution on overlay a text onto video.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I presume that the text that you want to overlay will change from one video to another. If that's not the case, you can create a PNG/BMP image with the text and then use the 'static' [image overlay option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/media-services-advanced-encoding-with-mes#overlay) via the Standard Encoder.

If you indeed need 'dynamic' text overlays, then you will need to use the Premium Encoder. Please contact us via mepd@microsoft.com, and we'll provide instructions on how to get access to the Workflow Designer tool, which you will need in order to make use of the Premium Encoder. There is an example of using the Premium Encoder for such text overlays documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/media-services-media-encoder-premium-workflow-multiplefilesinput#customizing-component-properties).

Comment: using the 'static' image overlay option via the Standard Encoder. i had done but image has to map on Top-Right corner how we can set static image on Right-Corner that dynamically for any resolution video

Comment: You will have to do this in multiple steps: [1] Run a thumbnail job with the Standard Encoder, as in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/media-services-dotnet-generate-thumbnail-with-mes, [2] Read the metadata XML from the output Asset, and [3] Use the input width and height to calculate the desired location for the overlay image, and [4] Submit the overlay Job with the calculated preset